# Where I can find Batch... jsx file (Photoshop standard script)

Tags: photoshop, extendscript, photoshop-script

I need to find **Batch...** jsx file script that is standard script in photoshop. I know, all script are in Scripts folder, I see **Image Processor** there. But cannot find **Batch...** .jsx file.
[image]

Comment: I don't believe that feature is an independant script

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for are two scripts, "CSX-1_3.jsx" and the library it uses, "stdlib.js" - but it depends on which version of PS you're using. The old location used to be in the /Presets/Scripts/ directory.